# How do I pause/resume a timer when a button from sibling component is clicked?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am new to Angular. How do i send a message between siblings component? For example, one of my component has a timer. The silbling component has a stop button. When this button is clicked, i want to pause the timer.

My component with a timer:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test.component.css']
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {

  public this.time: number = 0;
  public uiTimerId;

  constructor() { }

  private timer(): void {
    ++this.time;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.start = new Date().getTime();

    this.uiTimerId = window.setInterval(this.updateTimer.bind(this), 1000);
  }



}
```

My timer html:

```
{{ time }}
```

The Parent component html:

```
<app-header></app-header>
<app-test></app-test>
```

My other component (silbling)

```
<nav>
  <button>Pause Timer here</button>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a subject in a service, and then subscribe to it in the component to see when it's clicked.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using EventEmitter and subscribe to it to change the start/stop time. When a sibling component click stop button, it will call the method in service which emit the EventEmitter. The TestComponent will subscribe to this EventEmitter value and stop the time.

I create a [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dshnaf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) for you